# Update Query using composite PrimaryKey

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to update a column in a table with a composite primaryKey using Hibernate.
    I have written sql preparedStatement for the same.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
Class Student{

@EmbeddedId        
private StudentKey studKey;

@Column(name = "STUD_NAM")
private String name;

.....   
}

@Embeddable
public class StudentKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "STUD_ID")
    private int studId;

    @Column(name = "R_RUL_BEG_DT")
    private java.sql.Date beginDate;
    ....

    }
```

**Query :**

```
update Student set priority=(priority+1) where studKey.studId = ? and priority between ? and ?
```

I'm Getting the below exception,
`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'studKey.studId' in 'where clause'`.

Any Suggestions please? I cant use entity objects for update operation (**session.saveOrupdate()**), 
    since i will be constructing this query dynamically based on some conditions.

Comment: Why can't you use `entityManager.createQuery(...).executeUpdate()`? In SQL you will have to reference the column names (e.g. `STUD_ID`) instead of the property names (`studKey.studId`).